# Making Chrome extension make an existing tab active and canceling the incoming request with chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest listener

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a search app and when a user tries to navigate to the URL of a search result, I want to:
A) open a new tab with that URL if they don't already have that URL open in an existing tab, or
B) if they already have a tab with that URL open, make that existing tab active and refrain from opening another new tab with that same URL.

Separately from the code below, I have a currentTabs dict that's keeping track of the tabId and URL of each open tab so that I can compare the incoming URL to the already open URLs.

I'm trying to add a listener on

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest
```

to accomplish this. I'm using a query string like ?from_my_app=true so that I only implement this behavior on links from my app rather than any time someone tries to navigate to a URL they already have open. My code looks like this:

```
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        if (details.url.match(/?from_my_app=true/)) {
            var strippedUrl = (details.url.split('?from_my_app=true')[0];
            var matchedUrl;

            if (currentTabs.tabs) {
                // get the first pre-existing tab that has this url 
                matchedUrl = currentTabs.tabs.filter(x => x[1] == strippedUrl)[0];
            }

            if (matchedUrl) {
                // make the pre-existing tab with this url active
                // and cancel the opening of a new tab opening this url

                chrome.tabs.update(matchedUrl[0], { active: true });
                return { cancel: true }
            } else {
                // if this URL isn't already open in a tab, remove the
                // ?from_my_app=true query string and open it in a new 
                // tab

                return { redirectUrl: strippedUrl };
            }
        }
    }, 
    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

The issue I'm running into is that the

```
return { cancel: true }
```

executed when a URL is already open in another tab is causing the tab to not load at all and say " is blocked.
Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension." Clearly I'm using the API wrong - the behavior I'm looking for is for it to basically make the incoming request "fail silently" and just do the navigating to the existing tab while not opening a new tab at all. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: I guess you can do it in a content script by listening to click event and cancel it if the event target is an existing link.

Comment: My bad, I should've been more clear - a node macOS app is kicking off the link opening using the opn library (https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn) rather than a webapp running in Chrome, so I don't believe that approach would work since there's not actually a click event I could call e.preventDefault(); on?

Comment: If that node app is yours, you can communicate with the extension via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) API.

Comment: Thanks - I took a quick look at the native messaging and was just about to switch to that but I realized that the listener is actually giving me what I need to do this smoothly by passing the tabID in the details parameter of the listener's callback. I ended up doing this by removing the return { cancel: true } and switching that if branch to read as follows:                     
 `chrome.tabs.update(matchedUrl[0], { active: true });
                    chrome.tabs.remove(details.tabId);`